Trouble matching BER curve for simulated bit signals with theoretical BER curve using DBPSK
I'm trying to create simulate actually transmitting and receiving some bits for a binary DPSK signal (DBPSK). So generate a sine wave at a given sample rate and frequency, then for each bit I'll adjust the phase of the sine wave (if it's a 1 the phase will change by 180 degree compared to the previous bit signal, and if the bit is a 0 the phase will stay the same). Then I add some noise to that relative to an SNR and the demodulate the noisy signal by comparing the phase of the current bit with the previous bit. This is all working as expected, but I'm having a hard time actually getting an error to occure. The theoritical probability of error for DBPSK is $P_e = 1/2e^{-E_b/N_0}$, so when my signal power is equal to my noise (SNR of 1), i'd expect to get about 20% of my bits in error... and that's not happening currently, and i'm not quite sure why.
Below is the python code i'm using to generate the simulated and theorical BER curves
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
SNR_dB = np.arange(-9, 10, 1)  # SNR values in dB from 0 to 10
numBits = 10 ** 1  # Number of bits to transmit

Fs = 20000
bitRate = 10
freq = 3000
tukeyRatio = .25
samplesPerBit = int(Fs/bitRate)

#create the bit signal which will flip between 0 and 180 degrees phase later for modulation
t = np.arange(0, samplesPerBit / Fs, 1 / Fs)  # Time vector
bitSignal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)

berSimulated = []

for snr_db in SNR_dB:
    # Convert SNR from dB to linear scale
    snrLinear = 10 ** (snr_db / 10)

    # Generate random bits
    bits = np.random.randint(0, 2, numBits)

    # modulate bits into a signal
    phases = [] # will be a list of 1's and -1, where -1 is a phaseshift of 180 degrees
    currPhase = 1
    bitSigLen = len(bitSignal)
    for bit in bits:
        if bit == 1:  # do a phase shift on a one
            currPhase *= -1
        phases.extend(bitSigLen * [currPhase])
    # add up bitSignals for each bit we have, them flip the ones that need to be flipped
    txSignal = np.array(len(bits) * list(bitSignal)) * np.array(phases)

    #calculate power of the signal
    signalPower = np.mean(txSignal ** 2)

    # Noise standard deviation
    noisePower = signalPower / (snrLinear)
    noiseSTD = np.sqrt(noisePower)

    # Generate AWGN noise
    noise = noiseSTD * np.random.randn(numBits * samplesPerBit)

    # Received signal
    rxSignal = txSignal + noise

    # demodulated signal
    # do auto correlation with previous bit to determine phase. if phases are the same the values will be possitive
    correlatedSig = rxSignal[samplesPerBit:] * rxSignal[:-1 * samplesPerBit]

    # sum the correlated values for each bit
    receivedBitsSubVals = [sum(correlatedSig[currBit * samplesPerBit:(currBit + 1) * samplesPerBit]) for currBit in
                           range(numBits - 1)]

    # Evaluate the bits
    receivedBits = (np.array(receivedBitsSubVals) <= 0).astype(int)

    # calculate number of bit errors
    errors = np.sum(bits[1:] != receivedBits)

    # save BER for plotting later
    berSimulated.append(errors / (numBits - 1) + .00000001) # adding .00000001 just to have a value > zero

# # Analytical BER curve
berDbpsk = 0.5 * np.exp(-10 ** (SNR_dB / 10))

#
# # Plot BER curves
fig = plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(SNR_dB, berSimulated, marker='o', linestyle='-', label="Simulated BER")
plt.semilogy(SNR_dB, berDbpsk, marker='x', linestyle='--', label="Theoretical Binary DPSK BER $1/2 \cdot e^{-E_n/N_0}$")

plt.title("BER vs. SNR for DBPSK over AWGN")
plt.xlabel("SNR (dB)")
plt.ylabel("Bit Error Rate (BER)")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--')
plt.show()

print('Finished...')


Note that a $1e^-8$ error rate is added to the simulated BER curve just so it appears on the plot
I've looked at the demolated bit value before evaluating it to 0 or 1, and it does get noisier for netgative $SNR_{dB}$, but its still a not noisy enough to enduce errors Below are a couple of the values before bit determination. not that these are a low number of bits to help see them clearly, but even when i generate thousands of bits I still don't get any errors.


Any idea where I'm off at? I'd assume it's how I'm calculating my noise, but i'm not sure where that's off at.
Edit: I did this same simulation but going from -30dB to 10 dB SNR, and started getting errors below and SNR of -11, might makes it look like the simulated curve is all just shifted to the left compared to the theoretical curve, which increases my suspicion that there's a problem with how I'm calculating the noise, where the noise signal isn't matching the SNR properly. here's the updated plot


so, sorry for the lengthy comments; I missed your middle paragraph there. My apologies! Still, this calls for you really just plotting the intermediate steps: your generated random bits, your generated signal, your noisy signal, the bits after demodulation, and which bits get counted as error. Can't really help you much with this – it's classical manual debugging :)

@MarcusMüller , i've plotted the intermediate steps, and it'll all looks fine. My guess is that i'm off on my noise power or signal power or something. I just plotted this for -30dB SNR to 10dB, and the lower SNR's appear to give a BER shaped curve like i'd expect, just shifted. If I multiply my calculated signal power by 50, and replot everything, the simulated and theoretical plots are a much closer match, so that's what makes me think either my signal power or noise power calculations are off somewhere. my signal power is mean of txSignal^2, and my noise is signal power/ snr_linear

ah, misread your comment. So, you have something wrong with your noise or signal power! So, maybe measure and print the power of your signal and your noise, or their sum, in each step

@MarcusMüller I added in a calculation of both the modulation signal and noise signal before combining those and printed them out. I'm leaving the power of the signal constant and changing the noise, but the of the signal and noise powers are coming out to the same to be spot on as to that my target SNR is.

that's really surprising. I'm looking at your "Rx bit before evaluating to 0 or 1 at SNR -9" figure, and it looks more like a figure where the SNR is plenty positive! Also, the values are extremely high. Can you tell me which powers you saw?

One primary issue is that the noise is white and spread over the entire sampling bandwidth, so is not representing the expected SNR as the noise in SNR is just the that noise which is in the occupied bandwidth of the waveform. Given a sampling rate of 20 KHz and bit rate of 10 Hz (which represents the equivalent noise bandwidth of the rectangular pulsed waveform), for a real waveform the noise as entered should be increased by a factor half the sampling rate (10KHz) to the occupied bandwidth (10 Hz) which is $10\log_{10}(1000) = 30$ dB.
This explains 30 dB of a measured 20 dB difference, which still doesn't match the result but does put you closer.
Other notes:
I recommend simulating at complex baseband rather than trying to create an actual carrier frequency as it represents everything equally without requiring such a high sampling rate.
As Dilip mentioned in his now deleted comment, the non-coherent DPSK receiver by correlating the current symbol to the previous is suboptimum (I expect it to have a 3 dB degradation as the product of the independent noise in each symbol will approximately sum the noise). Using a clean local oscillator locked to the carrier frequency (coherent receiver) should have a 3 dB better result.
